# String concatenation

Tags: c#

```
string res1 = "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ","  + false +  ")"
```

in

```
res[0] = "IRS5555"
res[1] = "IRS001"
```

Output of this code is:

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",False)
```

but I want

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",false)
```

`false` in lower case.

Sorry for not providing full code...
false is not static...

```
    public static object GetElementDataType(string DataType)
     {
         ///Write here methos for fetching data type of current element.
          object res = null;
         switch (DataType.ToLower())
          {
              case "int":
                 res = 0;
                 break;
              case "double":
                 res = 0.0;
                 break;
              case "string":
                 res = "";
                 break;
              case "myboolean":
                 res = false;
                 break;
              default:
                 res = "";
                 break;
          }
         return res;
     }

     string res1 = 
         "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," 
                                     + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ","  
                                     + GetElementDataType("myboolean") +  ")"
```

then result is

```
 CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",False)
```

but i want

```
 CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",false)
```

if i pass double

```
 string res1 = "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ","  + GetElementDataType("double") +  ")"
```

then result is

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",0)
```

but i want

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",0.0)
```

if i pass string

```
string res1 = "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ","  + GetElementDataType("string") +  ")"
```

then result is

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001",)
```

but i want

```
CalcAPI.GetXElementValue("IRS5555","IRS001","")
```

Comment: How about `string res1 = "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ",false)"` ?

Answer (score 5):

If your false is constant there, then you can use simple string. And it`s better to use string format:

```
string res1 = string.Format("CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(\"{0}\",\"{1}\",false)", res[0], res[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `false.ToString().ToLower()`.

Comment: Jensen Add brackets () in the end of ToString;

Answer (score 0):

use ToLower() function like this

```
  string res1 = "CalcAPI.GetXElementValue(" + "\"" + res[0] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + res[1] + "\"" + ","  + false.ToString().ToLower() +  ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
false.ToString().ToLower()
```